# Twitter style Web Application based on LAMP, Symfony2, Backbone : possible?

Tags: web-applications, symfony, backbone.js

I am trying to develop a web-application that resembles Twitter. I decided to use Symfony2 for the Backend, but I have doubts with regards to the database (MySQL or MongoDB or something else?) and in general for the architecture that I should put in place.

My question is: Do I use Backbone's templating and views and I just use Symfony as a "web service" that will answer to Backbone's POST requests with the data? Is this how things should work? Or can I skip Symfony completely and only work with Backbone quering the database directly? (if this is possible..)

This is what I have in mind:

```
=> | HTML built with Backbone.js views (underscore or other templating engine] |
                                      |
=> | ajax request for data                                                     |
                                      |
=> | Symfony receives the request, queries the database and answers with the data |
                                      |
=> | The page content is updated/added/refreshed                               |
```

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

of course, you can use this stack. I already use it.
You have great control on routes, parameters required et response format

Moreover you can use already built in cache sytem (http, varnish..)

Look into  [RestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle), useful if you use Backbone.js rest sync method

Edit:

I would recommand sf2 for your webservice (JSON, response)

use backbone/marionnette stack in full html. Look into [Yeoman project](http://yeoman.io/) for building your frontend with backbone and deployement mechanism (beautiful)

Comment: Merci, j'ai juste un peu du mal a faire la separation entre qui fait quoi surtout par rapport aux Views et Routers (puisque Backbone et SF2 ont le meme systeme)

Comment: c'est pour ça, separe bien le front du backend. Crée des routes similaires dans sf2 et le routeur Backbone. dans l'absolu, Tu devrais pouvoir utiliser tes webservices que tu utilises un front avec backbone ou une version mobile (ie phonegap)

Comment: Apres avoir fait pas mal de recherche, j'ai une nouvelle question ici: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790448/mvc-front-end-and-mvc-back-end-wrong-architecture

Comment: tu peux regarder ces slides que j'ai trouvé avec symfony2 et backbone http://fr.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/how-kris-writes-symfony-apps  (slide 92)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think that Symfony 2 is a bit of overkill for the sole purpose of fetch data from the database, if you want to keep your template rendered by the client.

For this task I've used in the past a micro-framework, [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), which is built on top of Symfony 2 but it's much more lighter and concise.