# Mvc Front-end and Mvc Back-end: wrong architecture?

Tags: model-view-controller, symfony, backbone.js, ember.js

I am building a web-application that will be a twitter style one-page app, possibly ***with*** user authentication. 80% of the interactions happen in the front-end with JavaScript, and with the help of a backend who answers providing data from the db...

Until now my thought was to use Symfony2, plus an MVC framework for the front-end like Backbone or Ember (prefer Ember as it seems more documented and in general more organized and easier).

While I was getting into learning Symfony2, it came to my attention that many of the things that Symfony2 offers are of no use for my app. I don't really need its' views as views are going to be templated with Javascript, and I don't really need it's routers either as that will be also handled with states with JS on the front-end..

Symfony2 will only be used as a JSON-responding mechanism, I guess doctrine also helps someone who's not primarily a back-end guy to do the queries easily, and of course for the Authentication. I guess FORMS are also handled by JavaScript.

I've seen lots of other questions regarding Symfony2 and backbone, RESTful, etc. There are many different answers, some say you need a Bundle to create RESTful APIs (why?) - others say you need Bundle for the complete Integration of Backbone/Symfony2, others say you just need to query JSON data with Symfony2 and Serialize them and send them back, so nothing special..

So my question is: Seems like Symfony2 is an overkill for this kind of APP. But considering this is an opportunity-to-learn project, is it really a problem? (performance-wise, or not playing well with the Front-End). And the subquestion to that is, can you provide of any working example on Symfony2 integrated with an one-page web-app? I've seen different elements, but nothing as a whole so I can know what am I trying to achieve code-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Symphony2 but sounds a lot like most ember+rails projects. These apps use very little of the rails framework. One could make the case that a lighter framework is a better fit but shouldn't be a problem. More important is probably the lift it will take on your part to learn 2 new frameworks at once. If going w ember I would start by building an MVP that uses the ember fixture-adapter has no backend at all. Once you've got that working you can plug in whatever framework makes sense. The Fire Up Ember.js peepcode shows how to build an app this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have few routes, a thin model, little business logic, and no templating you might find it simpler to use something like Silex http://silex.sensiolabs.org/. Rather than disabling features of Symfony2 you can just add what you need to Silex. They both use the same building blocks just with a different ethos. Here's a nice presentation by @hhamon on using Silex for a REST API https://speakerdeck.com/hhamon/designing-rest-api-with-silex.